# Angular 6 How can i get another component onClick

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I have 2 components(homepage, modal-form-login).
Homepage components includes page with button (Log In).
Modal-form-login component includes Log In form.
How can i get this Log In component clicking button on Homepage component?

Comment: Try to use Dynamic Component Loader. more info https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader

Comment: If you want a modal (like it's written in the name of your component), Angular Material dialog can help you: https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview

Answer (score 3):

If you want to navigate to login component then use `Router` to navigate, import `Router` on top of your homepage component

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
```

inject then into constructor

```
constructor(private router: Router) {        
}
```

then add `click` event to your homepage button something like this

**HTML**

```
<button (click)="navigate()">Login</button>
```

**Homepage Component ts file**

```
navigate() {
        this.router.navigate(['/login']);
}
```

If you want to open login component as modal, then you should create login component with modal dialog of bootstrap, then use [Dynamic component loader](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader) to open modal.

Answer (score 1):

Add a click event to your button and add your code

```
function btnClick() {
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/path');
};
```

inject router in your component for using it